# Mongoose pull an element from an array field and push the new element at the same index from where it was removed

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose

There is a schema like this:

```
let authorSchema = new Schema ({
books: [{
    type: SCHEMA.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'book', //book is some other model
  }] 
})

let autorModel = MONGOOSE.model('author', authorSchema );
```

The document created for this model will be like this

```
//before

{

"result":{

"books": ["id1","id2","id3"],
"createdAt": "2019-08-07T13:20:49.427Z",
"updatedAt": "2019-08-08T10:15:31.474Z",
"id": "5d4ad031b0e1c8001c4a41ea"

}

}
```

Now I want to update this document by updating the books field and removing the id at the 2nd index (id2) and in place of that add a new id (newId) at the same index

so I want my document to look something like this

```
//after
{

"result":{

"books": ["id1","newId","id3"],
"createdAt": "2019-08-07T13:20:49.427Z",
"updatedAt": "2019-08-08T10:15:31.474Z",
"id": "5d4ad031b0e1c8001c4a41ea"

}

}
```

I read about the [$position](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) operator, but I can't find any solution where I can remove (pull) one element from an array and replace it ( push at the same index)  with a new element.

Comment: You can't do this in one query as it's not possible to get the index of removing element. What you can do is, find the record, replace the values in array and save it again with updated value.

Comment: but that won't replace the new element at the same index from where the old element was removed

Answer (score 0):

First find the record, replace the values in array and save it again with updated value, this is how you could do that:

```
const idToRemove = 'id2';
const idToInsert = 'newId';

autorModel.findOne({
        'books': idToRemove       // or if you have some other filter criteria
    }) 
    .then(async (result) => {
        if (!result) {
            console.log("No Record Found.");
        } else {
            const index = result.books.indexOf(idToRemove);
            result.books.splice(index, 1, idToInsert);
            await result.save();
            console.log('Record Updated Successfully.');
        }
    })
    .catrch(err => {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
        // Do something with error
    });
```

P.s: You may need some modifications as i couldn't get a chance to try the code.

hope this helps :)